# displaying arraylist item in jsp page one by one

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have a table that stores different Questions along with options with format.I am storing all this in an arraylist within a session in servlet.Now,i am getting this session in jsp page from servlet.

I want to display one question with its option at a time and then that questions should not be printed next time.It should get incremented to the next question.

I have doubt in this ,how do i implement this logic.Whatever i have tried till now displays all questions in jsp page.

please help.

Comment: @mohamedrias i have trid this: Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
String element;
while(itr.hasNext())
{
 element = itr.next(); 
 System.out.print(element + " ");
}
System.out.println();
%>

<%= out.println(element)  %>


but this is printing the whole content of the database in jsp page.i want just one to be shown at a time and each time a question is shown in jsp,that particular question should not be shown next time.

Comment: Create an instance variable in your jsp and increment it each time. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `instance variable` in your jsp and `increment` it each time.

```
<%! int i = 0;%>
```

It makes i stay around after execution. Each time you run the page, the last value of i stays in memory.

for getting one particular question:

```
 <%

    List list = fetchyourlisthere();

    // check its size

    if(i<list.size()) {

      list.get(i);

    // this will return you the object for that particular question.

     // now increment i

     i++;
    }

    %>
```

so each time the page loads, you will have new question from the list.

Comment: Now the question is getting printed but in the same column,my options are also there.so how do i display the whole column,ie ,the question along with the options..

Comment: Now using list.get(i) you will get the object. Now with that use scriptlets to inject the data in appropriate html tags.

Comment: List list=(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("userList");
if(i<list.size()){
 s=list.get(i).toString();
 i++;
 
}
System.out.println(s);
%>
<% out.println(s); %>




I am doing this but m getting only the first column value ,ie, the questions alone not the options which exist in the same column.

Comment: Yes. i thought you stored an object containing question and options as properties. You have stored only string in the arraylist?

Comment: insert into question values("S","S","S","S","S","S");

like this..only strings,question will be their with its 4 option.Now i want to display each whole column at a time,ie,questions and particluar options

Comment: That's your db query. When you get that in your DAO, You need to create an object of "Question" class and have properties question, option1, option2, etc and after populating the object must push it to arraylist.

Comment: question was how are you storing that inside arraylist?

Comment: yes inside arraylist in my DAO class and getting it in servlet as session.this arraylist has question number,question and 4 options.these all i want to print on jsp.

Comment: i think iterator should be used.but how do i print just one column alone not the full database columns.